# why is the my BlocBuilder not updating the UI?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have a functionality which is liking, and unliking a product, but the UI isn't updating according to the liking and unliking of the product, here is my setup, in my card widget there is a button that triggers the behaviour and it has a child that should be updating when the button is pressed:

```dart
BlocBuilder<LikeOrUnlikeProductCubit,
    LikeOrUnlikeProductState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    if (state is LikeOrUnlikeProductSuccessState) {
      return IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print(medicament.isFavourite);
          context
              .read<LikeOrUnlikeProductCubit>()
              .likeOrUnlikeMedicamentEvent(medicament);
          print(medicament.isFavourite);
        },
        icon: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 15,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
          child: Icon(
            medicament.isFavourite
                ? Icons.favorite
                : Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
            size: 15,
            color: medicament.isFavourite
                ? Colors.red
                : Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        print(medicament.isFavourite);
        context
            .read<LikeOrUnlikeProductCubit>()
            .likeOrUnlikeMedicamentEvent(medicament);
        print(medicament.isFavourite);
      },
      icon: CircleAvatar(
        radius: 15,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
        child: Icon(
          medicament.isFavourite
              ? Icons.favorite
              : Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
          size: 15,
          color: medicament.isFavourite
              ? Colors.red
              : Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

and here is my cubit in case you are curious:

```dart
class LikeOrUnlikeProductCubit extends Cubit<LikeOrUnlikeProductState> {
  LikeMedicamentUsecase likeMedicament;
  UnlikeMedicamentUsecase unlikeMedicament;
  LikeOrUnlikeProductCubit(this.likeMedicament, this.unlikeMedicament)
      : super(LikeOrUnlikeProductInitialState());

  Future<void> likeOrUnlikeMedicamentEvent(Medicament medicament) async {
    if (medicament.isFavourite) {
      final failureOrUnit = await unlikeMedicament(medicament);
      emit(_mapFailureOrUnitToState(failureOrUnit));
      return;
    } else {
      final failureOrUnit = await likeMedicament(medicament);
      emit(_mapFailureOrUnitToState(failureOrUnit));
      return;
    }
  }
}

LikeOrUnlikeProductState _mapFailureOrUnitToState(
    Either<Failure, Unit> either) {
  return either.fold(
    (failure) =>
        LikeOrUnlikeProductFailureState(message: _mapFailureToMessage(failure)),
    (_) => LikeOrUnlikeProductSuccessState(),
  );
}

String _mapFailureToMessage(Failure failure) {
  if (failure is EmptyCacheFailure) {
    return EMPTY_CACHE_FAILURE_MESSAGE;
  } else if (failure is CacheFailure) {
    return CACHE_FAILURE_MESSAGE;
  } else {
    return UNEXPECTED_FAILURE_MESSAGE;
  }
}
```

I added the print statments to see if the liking and unliking of the product is working, and it does, but the ui isn't being updated, I don't know why

Comment: Bloc builder won't trigger if you emit same state one after another. In your case you are emitting LikeOrUnlikeProductSuccessState() for both like and unlike operations. So for second time i.e. for unlike operation bloc builder will not invoked. Use different state for like and unlike

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by simply emiting a new state when the method gets triggered, because `BlocBuilder` won't trigger unless a state changes.

Comment: If this is the solution for your problem then mark it as solved. So people like me don't waste their time reading your code.

Comment: it says "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"

Comment: that was a really long 2 days I guess